# Is there any barcode generator extension for Yii framework 2.0?

Tags: php, yii2, barcode

Using Yii framework 2.0 I want to generate a list of barcode. I am trying to find barcode generator extension for Yii framework 2.0 on the Internet, but no luck. I did find only  barcode generator extensions for Yii 1.

Does anyone know any good barcode generator extensions for Yii 2.0 with a good documentation?

Comment: What is the one you found for Yii1? Perhaps it can be ported.

Comment: you visit this link to get answer....`http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-barcode-generator-8-types/`

Answer (score 2):

you visit this link to get answer....http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-barcode-generator-8-types/‌​

```
<html><div id="showBarcode"></div></html> <!--This element id should  be passed on to options-->
use barcode\barcode\BarcodeGenerator as BarcodeGenerator;

$optionsArray = array(
'elementId'=> 'showBarcode', /* div or canvas id*/
'value'=> '4797001018719', /* value for EAN 13 be careful to set right values for each barcode type */
'type'=>'ean13',/*supported types  ean8, ean13, upc, std25, int25, code11, code39, code93, code128, codabar, msi, datamatrix*/

);
echo BarcodeGenerator::widget($optionsArray);
```